# How to specify the size Yandex maps?

Tags: yandex-maps

The problem with the options `property.panelMaxMapArea`
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Balloon-docpage/#param-options.panelMaxMapArea

How do I specify the size of the map, so the `balloon` in the form of a panel was only if the map width is less than 480px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, documentation contains inaccuracy description, just use setter for options properties, something like this:

```
balloon.options.set('panelMaxMapArea', 480);
balloon.options.set('closeButton', false);
// and etc...
```